# Assign Javascript .append() variable to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How would I store the following Javascipt variable 'money' as a PHP variable on the same page.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var money = 0;
$(".target").change(function () {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
money = optionSelected.attr("data-price");
alert(money);
$( ".overlay-content" ).append(money);
 // show popup when selecting a country from the drop-down
$('.overlay-bg').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); 
$('.overlay-content').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'});
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country"
                    class="validate[required] input_styling target"
                    style="background: #FFFFFF;">
                <option value="">Please Select a Country</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan" data-price="29.95">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands" data-price="29.95">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania" data-price="29.95">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria" data-price="29.95">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa" data-price="29.95">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="Andorra" data-price="14.95">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola" data-price="29.95">Angola</option>
</select>
```

**HTML - Overlay-content (Popup - DIV)**

```
<div class="overlay-bg">
      <div class="overlay-content">
          <p>You have selected a country of residence outside of the United Kingdom.</p>
          <p>Please note we only accept credit card payments from UK customers.</p>
          <p>If you are a customer from outside the UK, please click the
          Paypal icon to be taken through to Paypal checkout to complete your order.</p>
          <td width="185" align="center" valign="middle">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
            <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_1']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_2']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_3']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?=$shipping?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$r['order_total']?>" />
            <input type="image" src=""
                   name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
            </form>
          <p>However, if you are a UK customer and simply made an error,
          please click below to return to the checkout page.</p>
          <p>Thank you</p>
          <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

At the moment I've managed to get the `data-price` value to be outputted as an alert and appended to the `<p>Thank you</p>` element within the popup DIV. This was purely for testing that the right value was being passed.

Instead I would like to store the `money` JS variable as a PHP variable i.e. `$shipping`. I've tried to POST the variable as follows:

```
$.post('pay_cart1.php',{'data-price':money},function(result){ alert (result) }
```

And then retrieve the value with $_REQUEST as PHP i.e.

```
$shipping =$_REQUEST['data-price'];
```

However, the alert shows the content of a random CSS file on my server and the `$_REQUEST` variable array is empty and returns a NULL/blank value.

Is anybody able to assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [**this**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) as you clearly dont understand how php and js works and this will make things a bit easier.

Then, what you can do here instead of sending data to server just [set that data-price value into shipping hidden input](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) value for example:

```
$("input[name='shipping']").val(money);
```

This way your hidden input will have value set as you wanted. And this is what you can do with js on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and do a **var_dump($_POST)**:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "pay_cart1.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : { data-price : money },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
       //if success
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
       //if error
    }
});
```